# How to delete uploads not in media library?

Tags: uploads, media

How to delete uploads not in media library? I have lot of images in my uploads folder but doesn't in media library. Exist some method how this do it?

Comment: How that happened? Did you upload files directly to the server instead of using the media manger? You can try the plugin [Add From Server](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/) to import the files into the media manager and detele from there or just delete the files using FTP or any other method to access the server. (Note: the linked plugin is old and I have never use it, I don't know it works correctly or not).

Comment: I don't know how it happened. But I found right way. I found each files in uploads dir and detect if file name exist in media library. If not I deleted these files.

Comment: Asking for plugin recommendations is off topic. Please read the help centre info.

Comment: @BradDalton I don't see where the OP was asking for a plugin. He wanted to know if there was "some method."

Comment: If they are not linked to database you will need to manually delete theme  (via ftp or hosting file manager)